# How to register a URL schema in Windows to be opened as a parameter of a web page on the default browser?

Tags: windows, url

I would like Windows automatically open a web page on the default browser with a parameter as part of the URL such as "http://MyDomain/MyApp.asp?P1=MyParameter" when a user type in something like "MyURL:MyParameter" in the RUN box. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

[Registering an Application to a URL Protocol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914.aspx). In the url handler application, compose a new url based on the incoming url, then call ShellExecute with the url.

Comment: Is it possible that we directly use the default browser to handle the URL by only changing the Windows Registry such as:

Comment: which "the url" you are talking about? the browser is already capable of handling http but is not capable of handling MyUrl as it neither registers nor understands the url.